Select application by AID in JavaCard SIMToolkit application
I want to develop a SIM Toolkit applet and inside that I want to access some files in file structure of UICC inside my applet.
The normal file select command is like this:
sim.select(SIMVIEW.FID_MF);

or
sim.select((short)0x3F00);

I should note that sim.select is a method of sim.access.SIMVIew class.
However I have no idea how to select files/applications by their AID which its length may more than 10 bytes.
